# Repetition of articles

Tags: articles

The rules of articles say that if the same noun is being referred to, the article should not be repeated. In this context, is the following sentence correct?

An ass can never become horse.

Or, should it be like this?

An ass can never become ***a*** horse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the article does not refer to the same noun. In the first case it refers to "ass", in the second it refers to "horse".

Hence the second is correct, while the first is wrong.